# Why does this rising-edge detector fail when connected to this t flip-flop?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is for the Minecraft Bedrock edition (on Xbox One).

I've built a simple redstone circuit that combines a t flip-flop using repeater-locking based on [this design](http://minecraft101.net/redstone/redstone-latches.html) and a rising-edge detector based on the "circuit breaker" design [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pulse_circuit#schematic_gallery:_rising_edge_detector).

[image: t flip-flop connected to rising edge detector, viewed from above]

The bottom stone block in the picture has a sticky piston underneath it facing towards the block, as per the "circuit breaker" design I linked to above.

If I press the button in the state shown, I would expect to see the section between the t flip-flop and the rising edge detector to turn on steady, and to see the lamp in the bottom left light up for three ticks and then turn back off.

In reality, the rising edge detector doesn't seem to work when it is driven by the output of the flip-flop. The piston goes up, but the repeater after the piston never gets activated.

If I place a lever inline and use that instead of the flip-flop, the rising edge detector works as expected.

I don't see any reason this wouldn't work. What am I missing?

**Edit**: It seems that if redstone signal passes through a repeater at all, the "circuit breaker" rising-edge detector described above doesn't work. Does this work on the Java Minecraft? Does this have something to do with how blocks are "updated"?

**Edit 2:** I think I've refined the problem a little bit. If redstone passes directly to the sticky piston, the sticky piston will do a one-tick update on all the blocks around it – meaning the repeater just before the lamp gets activated. If redstone passes through a repeater before reaching the sticky piston, the sticky piston is activated but it does not do a one-tick update to the blocks around it – meaning the repeater never gets activated.

Comment: It works fine for me. Try rebuilding it in a new world from this screenshot, maybe there's something weird in your current world. BTW, this does not mean that it's an invalid question, it could be a bug.

Comment: Wait, you're playing on a console? Well, that changes everything. Then I can't test it. But you used the wrong tag, [tag:minecraft] is only for the original.

Comment: @FabianRöling yes, I'm on console. thank you for updating my tags. i also added a sentence at the top to make that clear.

Comment: i've also opened a bug report [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-50559) so we'll see if they respond.

Comment: geez louise. apparently "console" edition is different than "bedrock" edition. i'm playing bedrock edition. microsoft really made it awfully confusing to know what version you're playing... thank you to the folks who have helped me fix my tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By routing the output of the flip-flop to a piston that connects a torch to the circuit breaker this bug can be circumvented:

[image: Fixed circuit]

Comment: this works! thank you. i guess it lets the circuit breaker be "directly" powered by the redstone torch. i guess the circuit breaker can't be powered indirectly via a repeater. (is this true on Java minecraft as well?) another solution is to use comparator-subtraction to implement the rising edge detector.

Comment: This bug doesn't happen on Java.